# How to clip Spatiallines with Spatialpolygons in R?

Tags: r, spatial, clip

Given:

```
library(sp)

l1 = cbind(c(2,4,6),c(3,2,5))
rownames(l1) = letters[1:3]
l2 = cbind(c(3,6,4),c(4,3,4))
rownames(l2) = letters[1:3]
l3 = cbind(c(2,9),c(4,5))
rownames(l3) = letters[1:2]
Sl1 = Line(l1)
Sl2 = Line(l2)
Sl3 = Line(l3)
Ll1 = Lines(list(Sl1), ID="a")
Ll2 = Lines(list(Sl2), ID="b")
Ll3 = Lines(list(Sl3), ID="c")
Sl = SpatialLines(list(Ll1,Ll2,Ll3))

Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1),ID="x")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), ID="y")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3), ID="z")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)

plot(SpP, col = 1:3, pbg="white")
lines(Sl, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

What I´m looking for is a way to clip all Spatiallines by Spatialpolygons in one step. 
Output should be a Spatiallines-object that represents the parts of the input Spatiallines which are inside of each feature of the Spatialpolygon.

What I tried is this:

```
 Sl_subset <- Sl[SpP, ]
```

and:

```
int<-gIntersection(SpP,Sl)
```

What I don´t know is how I can "call" the features of the Spatialpolygon.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand.

Comment: I do not understand what exactly you want as an output.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?